# Cannot insert nullable value in sqlite db

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using `sqlite` and I'm trying to insert a `DateTime` value, now happen in some case that the value's `null` and I get this warning:

> nullable object must have a value

the code that cause the fault is this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", item.Start?.DateTime.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

`command` is the `SQLiteCommand` and `item` is a `Google Calendar Event` (I'm using the Google Calendar API).

How you can see I've tried to fix declaring `Start` as nullable with `?` but I got the same problem.

The value of `Start` is this: `{Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventDateTime}`

This is an image of the properties contained into `.Start`:

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwC7G.png)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case the object is C# null you should use DB null which is DBNull.Value

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", (item.Start) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: I need to access to `.Start?.DateTime.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).` So I can't use the ?? operator.

Comment: no , if you need that , you should use an if statment